# Titanium nl.fokkezb.drawer change statusbarstyle

Tags: ios, titanium, titanium-alloy, drawer

How I can change the status bar style of the drawer? I put this code in my index.tss file but doesn't work...

```
"#drawer": {
    openDrawerGestureMode: "OPEN_MODE_ALL",
    closeDrawerGestureMode: "CLOSE_MODE_MARGIN",
    leftDrawerWidth: 200,
    statusBarStyle: "STATUSBAR_BLACK"
},
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have to do something like this index.js

```
var mainWindow = NappDrawerModule.createDrawer({
    centerWindow: $.navController, 
    leftWindow: $.winLeft,
    rightWindow: $.winRight,
    closeDrawerGestureMode: NappDrawerModule.CLOSE_MODE_ALL,
    openDrawerGestureMode: NappDrawerModule.OPEN_MODE_ALL,
    leftDrawerWidth: 180,
    rightDrawerWidth: 220,
    statusBarStyle: NappDrawerModule.STATUSBAR_WHITE,
    orientationModes: [Ti.UI.PORTRAIT, Ti.UI.UPSIDE_PORTRAIT]
})
```

Thanks

Comment: Down voted because question was asked in titanium alloy format (indicated by the tss code sample), answer given is in titanium classic format. NappDrawerModule.STATUSBAR_WHITE is not exposed to alloy tss.